# Android размер чекбокса

Tags: java, android, checkbox, style, padding

Добрый вечер уважаемые! Подскажите пожалуйста такую вещь. У меня в приложении есть чекбокс. Пользователь когда кликает на него может промахнуться и ткнуть в ту область, внутри которой он расположен. Проблема в том, что клик по этой области имеет свой обработчик который крайне нежелательно вызывать по ошибке. 
Напрашивается простой вариант - чтобы пользователь не пормахивался, нужно сделать чекбокс покрупнее. Но делать его большим не очень хотелось бы. Может быть есть возможность сделать так чтобы чекбокс имел некие "невидимые" границы, клик по которым считался бы кликом по чекбоксу? Что-то вроде паддинга. В общем хотелось бы сделать его покрупнее но чтобы визуально он имел те же самые размеры, но  при этом вокруг него была бы невидимая рамка, клик по которой считался бы кликом по чекбоксу. Надеюсь понятно изложил. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 8):

Да, есть паддинги:

```
<CheckBox
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="this is check" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Здравствуйте, @JuniorThree!

Размеры `checkBox`'а я бы не менял, а сделал бы один из двух следующих вариантов (или оба сразу):

- **работа с нижним слоем**

Так как клик по нижнему слою не желателен без выделения `checkBox`'a, то можно в слушателе кликов нижнего слоя добавить условие, которое бы проверяло `checkBox`.

```
    { 
    //открылось тело слушателя нижнего слоя
    if(checkBox.isChecked()) {
       // сделать что-либо, если выбран
    } else { 
       // иначе вывести сообщение или ничего не делать // 
    }
    }
```

- **работа с самим `checkBox`'ом**

Следует вложить существующий `checkBox` в новый `LinearLayout`, который будет располагаться на месте `checkBox` [Извиняюсь за тавтологию]. И установить следующие параметры:

```
<LinearLayout 
       andoid:id="@+id/chbLL"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:padding="@dimen/padding_for_checkBox"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:clickable="true" >
             <CheckBox
                   android:id="@+id/myChB"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   ... здесь Ваши параметры checkBox'a ... />
</LinearLayout>
```

// стоит добавить, что ориентация `linearLayout`'a не имеет значения.

**Что пишем в классе ?**

После инициализации объектов добавляем слушателя кликов для `LinearLayout`'a с `id: chbLL`.

```
chbLL.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View arg0) {
                 if (myChB.isChecked()) {
                     myChB.setChecked(false);
                 } else { myChB.setChecked(true)); }
                 /*в итоге получается, что при клике по LinearLayout'у
                 будет изменяться на противоположное значение checkBox'a.
                 А обработчик кликов по checkBox'у у Вас есть уже. В нем
                 ничего не меняется.*/
           }
      });
```

**Подытожим:**

- первый вариант лучше тем, что есть маленькая защита от ложных нажатий, о которых Вы писали выше. Но нет расширения поля.
- второй вариант дает возможность сделать поле для мазил больше, но нет защиты. Кстати, во втором варианте можно убрать свойство `padding` у `LinearLayout` и добавить свойство `layout_margin` для `checkBox`'a. 
  Нужный вариант выбирать Вам, но можно их и объединить. Тоже решение за Вами.